# Error: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated on date string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a date that divide on year and month.

After the query got executed its giving me an error.

**Error**

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 418:        cn.Open()
>   Line 419:
>   Line 420:        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   Line 421:        Response.Write("Successfully Generated.")
>   Line 422:

Here's my code:

```
    Dim SQL As String = ""
    Dim AppMonth As DateTime = txtAppMonth.Text

    Dim Month As Integer = (AppMonth).ToString("MM")
    Dim Year As Integer = (AppMonth).ToString("yyyy")
    Dim cp_code As String = Left(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, 4)


    SQL = "exec birthday '" & Month & "', '" & Year & "', '" & cp_code & "'  "

    cn.ConnectionString = Cnstr()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn)
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
    cn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Response.Write("Successfully Generated.")
```

All answer will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does your stored procedure `birthday` look like?? What table are you trying to insert data into? (we need the table structure)

Comment: This probably means that somewhere, you are trying to insert data into a column with a fixed width (varchar, nvarchar or similar) but you are trying to insert more data than it will fit.

Comment: @Rune You're right I changed the limit of my variables and its now okay. thank you so much